# 羽を咲いている and 羽が咲いている difference

Tags: particle-が, particle-を

I've been told 羽を咲いている is incorrect. Can someone explain why I can't use を here?

Comment: Both look incorrect to me. What do you want to say in the first place? Maybe you wanted to write 花 instead of 羽?

Comment: I wanted to say "Wings are blooming".

Comment: @wing "wings are blooming" sounds rather poetic. It isn't standard English. What do you mean by 'blooming' in this context? Do you mean spreading/unfurling, or are you talking about a new pair of wings growing?

Comment: Yes I was trying to make it poetic. But I was told it should 羽を 咲かせている

Comment: I don't think this will translate well...

Comment: “Wings are blooming” isn’t really poetic in English – it’s just nonsensical. Wings don’t bloom or do anything that resembles blooming. You cannot take something that is barely intelligible in English and expect it to be any more understandable when translated – chances are it will be even _less_ understandable in translation.

Comment: It may not translate well, but some people here have a serious lack of imagination when it comes to English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because 咲く is an intransitive verb. Intransitive verbs don't take an object. を is an object marker.

～を咲かせる means "to make ～ bloom". It is causative.

Comment: While 「羽を咲かせる」 may be "grammatical", it makes little to no sense.  It does not sound poetic at all, either.  To be completely honest, it evokes pretty gross imagery.